# Map vim command line execution to a key

Tags: vim

So a lot of subversion repos I work with have a formatted first line that needs to be part of the commit, or it will be rejected.  I'd like to map a key in vim to do an "svn log --limit 1", find the line, and paste it under the current cursor location for when I'm writing a commit message (via `svn commit`).

I found this site that gives a great command for doing so: [link](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2009/03/10/vim-tip-of-day-running-external)

From inside vim, if I do a `:r !svn log --limit 1 | grep something`, the exact line I want from my subversion log is pasted under the cursor.  That's EXACTLY what I want to happen.

However, if I try to map this to a key (F9) in my .vimrc, it doesn't work.  here's the line:

`map <F9>:r !svn log --limit 1 | grep something`

However, instead of working, every time I open vim, I see the following:

```
$vim
!grep -n mystring /dev/null | tee /tmp/<random chars>

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, or how to map that command to a key.

Edit: apparently one thing I need to do is to escape the pipe character.  The mapping now becomes

`map <F9>:r !svn log --limit 1 \| grep something`

This gets rid of the errors when I start vim, but it's still not making it to my clipboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is actually pretty simple. The bar command separates two different commands on to the same line. What you *intended* is

```
map <F9> --> ":r !svn log --limit 1 | grep something"
```

But what you *got* is

```
"map <F9>:r !svn log --limit 1" | "grep something"
```

So this runs two different commands, the mapping and a grep command. To fix this, just use a `\|` in your mapping.

Now, there are a couple other things wrong with your command too:

- Because there are no spaces in `<F9>:r`, vim will map `<F9>:r` to `!svn log...` rather than mapping `<F9>` to `:r !svn...`. This can be fixed just by adding a space.
- This will not actually run the command unless you add `<cr>` at the end.
- It's good form to use `nnoremap` instead of `map`. This will prevent mapping conflicts.

Putting all of this advice together, the final command you should use is

```
nnoremap <F9> :r !svn log --limit 1 \| grep something<cr>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  Works like a charm and will help my workflow out immensely!

Comment: Glad to help! :)